# iPhone - CLLocationManager stops updating while trying to acquire current location

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to acquire the current location on an iOS device (specifically, my iPhone).
I'm using [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html) Apple example.

The timeout before I call stopUpdatingLocations is 60 seconds.
When I set the desiredAccuracy to be kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters, only 3 newLocations arrive to the didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation. The first one is the cached one, from long time ago. The next two ALSO have timestamps from more than 15 seconds, despite the fact that all 3 arrive within 5 seconds interval. All three of them contain bad horizontal accuracy. 
On the other hand, when I set the desiredAccuracy to be kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters, newLocations continue to arrive until I get an appropriate, exact one.
My WiFi is off and I'm indoors.

My question is: why when using the kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters accuracy I stop receiving updates early?

Comment: Im having, the same problem, getting crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Because when the location returned immediately satisfies the nearest accuracy, it stops? If this is not the case, can you show any logs or anything to further explain the situation if I have perhaps missed the point.

Comment: Thank you for the notion, I didn't mention a crucial part - they don't satisfy the nearest accuracy. Edited my question.